# Difference between NUnit and NUnit.Runner

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nunit, nunit-2.5.9

What is the difference between NUnit and NUnit.Runner packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NUnit package contains the NUnit framework library which lets you **write** tests.
NUnit Runners package contains some additional tools which lets you **execute** tests, for example using a GUI runner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I downloaded NUnit extension I was hoping 2 see Tools directory, unfortunately there was no tools directory at the version 2.6x.  Do you have any idea, whether NUnit.Runner package contains Tools directory or not?